# Resetting an Angular form with a model

Tags: angular, angular-template-form

I want to be able to reset an Angular form with some default values for it's model

```
<form>
  <input type="text" name="text" [(ngModel)]="model.text">
  <button type="reset" (click)="resetModel()">Reset</button>
</form>
```

and in the component

```
model = { text: 'Test' };

resetModel() {
  this.model = { text: 'Test' };
}
```

This doesn't work as the reset happens after the model is set and text is set to null by the reset.

The only two things I can figure out are one use a timeout like we used to pollute our AngularJs apps with like

```
resetModel() {
  setTimeout(() => { this.model = { text: 'Test' }; });
}
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5pdpml

or make the button a plain old button instead of a reset button and pass the form in to the reset method and call markAsUntouched and markAsPristine.

I don't really like either of these options.

I have tried giving the input a value so the reset has a default value but Angular still sets the model to null even though the input does have the text set by the reset.

Is there a way for a reset button to set a default form state rather than setting all of the bindings to null?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a way without using `setTimeout`. You can get the reference of the form and call either `reset` or `resetForm` methods (in this case both will work) to reset the value (and status).

```
<form #myForm="ngForm">
  <input type="text" name="text" [(ngModel)]="model.text">
  <button type="button" (click)="myForm.reset({ text: 'Test' })">Reset</button>
  <!-- <button type="button" (click)="myForm.resetForm({ text: 'Test' })">Reset</button> -->
</form>
{{ model | json }}
```

Here is the updated [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mkbpe5).

You should notice that the button is not of type `reset` but regular `button`, for some reason type `reset` doesn't work. I will research a bit more and hopefully find a reason why...

**EDIT**: Apparently, when using button `type=reset` it automatically resets the form values to their default values (in case of the `input` control that would be the value defined in the `value` attribute). That seems incorrect in Angular form context and shouldn't be used (bit more about that [here](https://github.com/telerik/kendo-angular/issues/1071)).

Furthermore, it is not even recommended using `reset` buttons in forms (as per [official documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/reset)) therefore I am quite confident that it is correct to use `type=button` in this case.

> You should usually avoid including reset buttons in your forms. They're rarely useful, and are instead more likely to frustrate users who click them by mistake (often while trying to click the submit button).

Finally, I will mention the difference between `reset` and `resetForm`. They are the same except that `resetForm` also affects the `submitted` state of the form (sets it to `false`). More about that [here](https://itnext.io/to-reset-a-form-or-to-resetform-555d3da47c52#1de5).

Comment: Thanks for the hint with the "Reset"-button-type!

Answer (score -1):

You could create a new class for your model:

```
export class Model{
text: string;
}
```

and then assign your model to a new instance of the class

```
model = new Model();
```

then in your form connect to this model object

```
<form>
  <input type="text" name="text" [(ngModel)]="model.text">
  <button type="reset" (click)="resetModel()">Reset</button>
</form>
```

to reset it in your controller set the model object to a new instance

```
resetForm(){
model = new Model();
}
```

Comment: This does not solve the issue, it is no different than using an object